# Should I nest a slider inside of <header> tag?

Tags: html, header, slider

I am currently working on a website, where the site will have a hero slider at the top of the page, under the navigation. Currently, I have written the code like this:

```
<header>
  <h1 class="site-title">Site Title</h1>
  <nav id="primary">
    <ul class="top-level">
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="hero-banner">
  <!-- Banner Content -->
</section>
```

But I am wondering if it would be appropriate to also include the hero slider inside of the `<header>` tag? In that case, the code would turn into this:

```
<header>
  <h1 class="site-title">Site Title</h1>
  <nav id="primary">
    <ul class="top-level">
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
      <li class="link">Link</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="hero-banner">
    <!-- Banner Content -->
  </section>
</header>
```

Visually, I would consider the hero banner to be grouped with the rest of the `<header>`, but I'm not sure if reflecting this in the code would be considered semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

From w3schools:

> The  element represents a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links.
>   A  element typically contains:
>
> - one or more heading elements (`<h1>` - `<h6>`)
> - logo or icon
> - authorship information

In the end, it's entirely up to you, it's not "bad practice" or "good practice" one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to put it outside the `<header>` tag. As it is not considered as an element of the menu nor the navigation bar. So you are good to go with the first code.